# Is there a way to upscale an image using a layer in a machine learning model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

For instance, consider I have a `(32,32,1)` input grayscale image. I want to use [EfficientNet](https://keras.io/api/applications/efficientnet_v2/#efficientnetv2l-function) or any other pre-trained model to classify the data (or basically use transfer learning of any sort). Since EfficientNet takes a minimum of `(75,75,3)` sized images, is it possible for to upscale my image using ONLY model weights?

For example, any combination of `Conv2D`, `Dense` etc which can work for my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use **tf.keras.layers.Resizing** which resizes an image input to a target height and width after the input layer inside your DL model. check the [doc](https://keras.io/api/layers/preprocessing_layers/image_preprocessing/resizing/) for more details. 
   or
2. If you read the images data from a folder you don't need to add a new layer to your model. You can use tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory [method](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory) and specify image_size (it's just an argument which is the Size to resize images to after they are read from disk) as your desired target size

Answer (score 1):

`Conv2D` would only decrease the size of the image.

You could use a 'deconvolution' layer: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2DTranspose
which is a trainable layer ; for example `strides=(3,3)` multiplies by 3 the width and the height of the image.

An example of use is given in https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan